# How to deserialize a xml string to a set of C# classes without having to declare a lot properties just for xml attributes?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I have the xml below and I am wondering how can it be deserialized to a set of classes without having to add tons of fields (to those classes) just for the sake of representing the different xml attributes (and their respective values).

I thought I could have something which support declarative xml attributes as .NET attributes on top properties that define xml elements.

```
<y:input xmlns:y='http://www.stuff.com/blahblah/42'>
    <y:datas>
        <y:instance yclass='Report' yid="report">
            <language yid='LANG_fr'/>
            <threshold>0.8</threshold>
            <typePeriod>predefinedPeriod</typePeriod>
            <interval>month</interval>
            <valuePeriod>April</valuePeriod>
            <fund yclass="Fund">
                <name>K</name>
                <performance yclass="Performance">
                    <typeValue>percent</typeValue>
                    <value>-0.05</value>
                </performance>
                [... lot of other fields ...]
            </fund>
        </y:instance>
    </y:datas>
</y:input>
```

Comment: You don't *have* to specify properties for all attributes, just specify the ones you need.

Comment: Still it adds confusion if you have business class properties that do not only translate to theit business elements as part of the xml. It would better that .net attributes could translate directly to xml attributes (or some options / workarounds (other than creating other fields) in case of const values for xml attributes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use ExpandoObject (part of System.Dynamic).

I tried a quick solution myself and was able to parse that xml successfully to a dynamic object.

What you need to do is:

1. Parse the string data to XDocument so you have an xml document object.

   `var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlData);`
2. I then converted the doc to a json string, you don't need to do this but it was the quickest way for me to test if this will work.
   (For this I needed to add the Newtonsoft.Json NuGet package.)

   `string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(doc);`
3. Then lastly I deserilzed the object like this:

   `dynamic dyn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(jsonText);`

Comment: isn't too slow to leverage the dynamic part>

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

I like using xml linq along with a nested dictionary :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XNamespace yNs = doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("y");
            Datas data = doc.Descendants(yNs + "datas").Select(x => new Datas() {
                instances = x.Descendants(yNs + "instance").Select(y => new Instance() {
                    instance = (string)y.Attribute("yid"),
                    language = (string)y.Element("language").Attribute("yid"),
                    threshold = (decimal)y.Element("threshold"),
                    typePeriod = (string)y.Element("typePeriod"),
                    interval = (string)y.Element("interval"),
                    valuePeriod = (string)y.Element("valuePeriod"),
                    fund = y.Elements("fund").Select(z => new Fund() {
                        fields  = z.Elements().GroupBy(a => a.Name.LocalName, b => b.Elements()
                            .GroupBy(c => c.Name.LocalName, d => (string)d)
                            .ToDictionary(c => c.Key, d => d.FirstOrDefault()))
                            .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, b => b.FirstOrDefault())
                    }).FirstOrDefault()
                }).ToList()
            }).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
    public class Datas
    {
        public List<Instance> instances { get; set; }
    }
    public class Instance
    {
        public string instance { get; set; }
        public string language { get; set; }
        public decimal threshold { get; set; }
        public string typePeriod { get; set; }
        public string interval { get; set; }
        public string valuePeriod { get; set; }
        public Fund fund { get; set; }
     }
    public class Fund
    {
        public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,string>> fields { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: a bit overconvoluted, just a builder method? I was more expecting a trick to leverage xml attribute as .net attribute

Comment: The dictionary is the trick.  I only had one sample of the fund (and attributes) and didn't know which elements you needed so I parsed the entire file.  Not Over-convoluted.  Very simple.

Comment: if that's the case can build it with a StringBuilder for most part ;-)

Comment: What does a string builder do for you?